# Is it possible to prevent ad-hoc formatting in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles, screen-reader

Our company targets blind people. To support screen readers, the documents must be properly styled with predefined semantic styles. However, some of our employees keep using ad-hoc styles (i.e., they set the font size, font weight, etc. individually for each heading), despite having had the training.

Is it possible to prevent *ad-hoc formatting* administratively, say in `normal.dot`, so they don't have any other chance but to learn to use semantic styles?

Comment: Unless you are using binary files rather than xml, it should be normal.dotm, not normal.dot. IMO, this is best addressed by training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to remove all formatting by selecting the entire document
and clicking on Clear All Formatting ([image]).
You could make it mandatory for everybody as final action for all documents.
Or even replace the Save action with a VBA macro inside `normal.dot`
that will
do "Clear All Formatting" on the entire document while saving.

Another possibility is forcing a document template on everybody as
the basis for all new documents, in which the styles are locked to the
ones in `normal.dot`.
This is done in the Styles pane, the Manage Styles icon, select your
styles and check the "Limit Formatting to Permitted Styles" check box.

These references contain more information and methods:

- [How to Restrict Style Changes in Microsoft Word](https://erinwrightwriting.com/how-to-restrict-style-changes-in-microsoft-word-tutorial/)
- [Create a Template that Stops Styles from Being Added to a Document](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T012698_Create_a_Template_that_Stops_Styles_from_Being_Added_to_a_Document.html)
- [Locking Document Formatting](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=731710&seqNum=14)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this information is exactly what I was looking for.